# find words with all vowels in order from a file

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have a large dictionary file with 300,000+ words in it and I'm trying to find all words with the vowels aeiou in that order and have only exactly 5 vowels. My current attempt does not seem to be working and for the life of me I don't understand why.

```
less mywords | grep -iE [^aeiou]*a[^aeiou]*e[^aeiou]*i[^aeiou]*o[^aeiou]*u[^aeiou]*
```

I think it get's all the words I'm looking for but there are a few words that pop up which I can not get rid of.

```
abstemiousnesses
ultraserious
```

There are a few other but they are in the same vein. Curiously, even if I add something like `[^u]*` to the front `ultraserious` keeping popping back up! Any solution would be fine however I would like it restricted to grep as we've been told it can be done using only grep.

Comment: Is something like `adventitious` valid?

Comment: No, the vowels have to appear in order and with no other vowels in between. I'll specify that, thanks.

Comment: in french `y` is also a vowel

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're not anchoring the expression.  It can match in the middle, so any vowels "outside" your match are allowed.

Add a ^ and $ to prevent that.

```
$ echo abstemiousnesses | grep -iE '[^aeiou]*a[^aeiou]*e[^aeiou]*i[^aeiou]*o[^aeiou]*u[^aeiou]*'
abstemiousnesses
$ echo abstemiousnesses | grep -iE '^[^aeiou]*a[^aeiou]*e[^aeiou]*i[^aeiou]*o[^aeiou]*u[^aeiou]*$'
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you, I can't believe I spent so much time on the problem and it was that!

Comment: See also the `-x` option.

Comment: @Achaldo you could also simplify the syntax a bit by saving the character class as a variable: `p='[^aeiou]'; grep -i "^$p*a$p*e$p*i$p*o$p*u$p*$" mywords`. Oh, and there is absolutely no reason to use `less` (or `cat` which would have been the natural choice), `grep` can take a file as an argument.

Comment: Following up on the second part of @terdon's comment: the traditional way of running a `grep` would be `grep (option(s)) (pattern(s)) (input_file(s))`. If you prefer to see the input up front, and it's a single file, you can say `< mywords grep (option(s)) (pattern(s))`, which makes the input easy to see while avoiding the ["useless use of `cat`"](http://superuser.com/questions/323060/what-is-the-general-consensus-on-useless-use-of-cat).

Comment: @Scott why? Why not just `grep -foo pattern file`? Why add an extra character?

Comment: @terdon: Simply for "readability". People tend to think in terms of "take this input and do this processing on it", and so it can be hard to perceive the meaning of a command that puts the input filename somewhere around column 83.

Comment: @Scott to each his own then :) I find the `<` syntax very obtuse and counter intuitive. Pretty much _all_ commands that take a file name as an argument are in the format of `command options input_file` and that is always the easiest to read to my eyes.

Comment: @terdon: My point, such as it is, is that some of us break out in hives when we see `cat (file) |`, and some people use it instinctively, so I was offering the OP a migration path.